# Wordpress redirects with query (?) strings - HTAccess File being wiped every 'x' amount of time

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

So I have been experiencing a rather brain confusing issue that seems to have quite a few conflicting issues.

On a new website (wordpress) I have setup we had lots of redirects that had query strings in them. Now all the redirect plugins I activated could not handle these so I found topics on here that helped me manually add these to the .htaccess file.

Here is an example (see lines that are **)

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
**RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} unit=32x10**
**RewriteRule ^unit\.php$ /available-units/32ft-x-10ft/? [L,R=301]**
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have a long list of these RewriteCond / Rules.

We noticed that after a period of time these manual redirects I added were all being wiped and the .htaccess file was reverting back to the normal version (see below). To prevent this, I changed the file permission to not writable.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

However, since doing this I am now unable to use Hide My WP and Really Simple SSL as they both require access to the .htaccess file.

Is there anything else I can do with these redirects that won't end up being wiped ?

Perhaps I am putting them in the wrong place within the .htacess file?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

MORE DETAILS ADDED

This is more query string redirects that are present....

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} unit=32x10
RewriteRule ^unit\.php$ /available-units/32ft-x-10ft-32x10/? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} unit=4579
RewriteRule ^unit\.php$ /available-units/32ft-x-20ft-4579/? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} unit=4147
RewriteRule ^unit\.php$ /available-units/unit-ref-4147/? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} unit=4768
RewriteRule ^unit\.php$ /available-units/2020-range-unit-ref-4768/? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ unit.php/available-units/32ft-x-10ft/?unit=32*10 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hello Jay. Should this line just replace ` **RewriteRule ^unit\.php$ /available-units/32ft-x-10ft/? [L,R=301]**` ?

Comment: Please check the question again as I have added more information.